# TYPO3 wec_contentelements for v 7.6.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Is there an extension like [`wec_contentelements`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/wec_contentelements) for TYPO3 7.6.x?

The current version of `wec_contentelements` does not work with version 7.6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension itself doesn't work in TYPO3 7.6, but there are are lot of other extensions inside the [TYPO3-Repository](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/) that provide the same kind of content-elements:

- VIMEO: [Video Content Element](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/videoce)
- YouTube: [Video Content Element](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/videoce)
- Slideshow: [Bootstrap
  carousel](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/koning_bootstrap_carousel)
- Local Menu: [You    can build this with TypoScript or
  Fluid! No need for an extension!](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/CreateAMenu/Index.html)

Comment: Mask is a similar extension which is compatible with TYPO3 7.6.x